# How can I index a tensor efficiently with specific condition in pytorch?

Tags: indexing, pytorch, tensor

I was tring to index a tensor with specific conditions in a efficient way in pytorch with GPU, instead of naively using loop with CPU.
Specificly, the input is a tensor whose shape is `[N_sampled, 3]` which stored N_sampled 3D points coordinaries. The conditions are `x_min < X < x_max and y_min < Y < y_max and z_min < Z < z_max`. The output should be a mask whose shape is `[N_sampled, 1]`.

I tried to use `torch.where(condition, input, other, *, out=None)`, however, it seems that the condition of `torch.where` can only be defined with only one condition. The experiments codes are as below.

```py
>>> a = torch.randn(2,3)
>>> a
tensor([[ 0.9133,  1.7252,  0.9825],
        [-0.2297, -1.1227,  0.9272]])
>>> b = torch.where((a[0]<0 and a[1]<0 and a[2]>0), a, torch.ones(2,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

The goal is to judge whether `N_sampled` points meet the condition in parallel, which can't be simply judged by boolean operation. A judge function is like:

```py
def fn(pts: torch.Tensor, grids: nn.Parameters, model: nn.Module):
    output = torch.tensor([False] * pts.shape[0]).unsqueeze(1)
    for i in range(num := pts.shape[0]):
        if model( grids(pts[i,:]) == 1:
            output[i] = True
    return output
```

How can I use `torch.where` to judge all points in parallel rather than using for loop?
The time of the following experiment codes are almost the same.

```py
def fn(input: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    output = torch.tensor([False] * input.shape[0]).unsqueeze(1)
    for i in range(num := input.shape[0]):
        if input[i,0] < 1 and input[i,1] < 1 and input[i,2] < 1:
            output[i] = True
    return output

c = torch.where( fn(a), 1, 0 )

for i in range(N_samples):
    b[i] = 1 if a[i,0] < 1 and a[i,1] < 1 and a[i,2] < 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a composition of several `torch.where` calls. You can compose them by multiplying:

```
# create random tensor for example
n_sampled = 100
A = torch.rand(m,3)
# define limits 
xmin = ...

x1 = torch.where(A[:,0] > xmin, 1,0)
x2 = torch.where(A[:,0] < xmax, 1,0)
y1 = torch.where(A[:,1] > ymin, 1,0)
y2 = torch.where(A[:,1] < ymax, 1,0)
z1 = torch.where(A[:,2] > zmin, 1,0)
z2 = torch.where(A[:,2] < zmax, 1,0)

# mask of size [n_sampled] with 1 where all conditions are met, 0 otherwise
mask = x1 * x2 *y1 * y2 * z1 * z2
mask = mask.unsqueeze(1) # to get to your desired [n_sampled,1] shape
```

From here you can easily index the base tensor. To be clear, in your example code you select the value from `A` wherever the condition is met and 1 everywhere where the condition is not met, which is not really a mask per se. Assuming what you want to do is select only the rows of `A` which meet the condition:

```
indices = mask.nonzero()[:,0]
A_sub = A[indices,:]
```

Alternatively, at the expense of clarity, you can use `torch.logical_and` or cast as integers and then add multiple conditions to get a single boolean expression to use in your `torch.where` condition.

```
torch.where( (  (A[:,0]>xmin).int() + (A[:,0]<xmax).int() ... (A[:,2]< zmax).int() ) == 6, 1,0)
```

Comment: Many thank for your help!
I wonder whether I could use customized function in torch.where.
i.e. `B = torch.where( fn(A), A, torch.zeros_like(A) )`
fn is a customized function whose input is A, output is bool.

Comment: Should work as long as the function returns a bool tensor of the same shape

Comment: I tried to use fn but it's not efficient, the question was replenished.

Comment: Sure, if your function uses a loop, it's going to be as inefficient as your initial solution. For high performance you need to either use jit to speed up looping or (more realistically as pytorch is specifically made for efficient vectorized computation) vectorize the operation using tensors. As is shown in this answer (no loops involved).